# Chrome 111 redirects Angular PWA mistaken for Chrome app

Tags: angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

We have an Angular 14 web app that is installed on computers as a progressive web app (PWA) using Google Chrome. Before the update to Chrome 111 it worked fine, but now when double clicking the icon the users are redirected to chrome://app with a popup saying "Old versions of Chrome apps won't open on Linux devices after December 2022. You can check if there is a new version available.". This happens under Linux and Windows. A link then suggests to turn this chrome app into a PWA, which it already should be. Using Microsoft Edge 110 for the install of the PWA works, so here double clicking opens the app directly. So far I couldn't find a clue in the release description of Chrome 111 that can explain why the PWA is not treated as such. The manifest file seems fine, so is the certificate. Hope someone can help!

I expected the app to open on double click. Instead Chrome redirected me to chrome://app where I could open it, but only after clicking away another warning popup

Does anyone know what changes in Chrome v111 makes it behave this way and what properties makes it confuse a PWA with a Chrome app?

**Update:**

I guess it has to do with the change [Migrating Chrome Apps to Progressive Web Apps](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/174381169?visit_id=638145696559245309-1248776229&p=chrome_app_deprecation&rd=1):

> March 2023: Chrome Apps will no longer be launchable on Windows, Mac, and Linux"

Answer (score 4):

Timing of March 2023 milestone mentioned in [Migrating Chrome Apps to Progressive Web Apps](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/174381169)
 checks out, but no leads yet on actual root cause, however, we have resolved our PWA issue with Chrome 111 with no changes to our PWA code or manifest just by un-installing it, **but with an extra step before re-installing it**.

NOTE: Un-installing ("removing") and re-installing, repeatedly (for us) does not solve the problem, but we accidentally discovered that the PWA does not seem to fully un-install the first time, and has to be removed twice before re-install:

**WORKAROUND (one-time)**

Uninstall as-usual from `chrome://apps` (right-click your PWA icon and select "Remove from Chrome", you do not need to check "Also clear data from Chrome") but **before closing Chrome**, refresh the `chrome://apps` page; you'll notice your PWA icon reappear with a red `!`. Do the un-install process again, then re-install.

**MISSING/GENERIC PWA ICON IN CHROME://APPS AFTERWARD?**

After completing the re-install, and despite everything working and your shortcut having your proper PWA icon on desktop/elsewhere, in the `chrome://apps` page, the PWA listed there may have a generic placeholder icon.

Might just be us, but we (coincidentally?) did not already have the `id` key/value in our PWA's `manifest.json` before all of this.

Despite the PWA continuing to work fine after the workaround, the `chrome://apps` page continued to show a generic placeholder icon.

**To resolve** (again, coincidental? clue?) we updated the PWA's `manifest.json` file in-place to include the `id` key/value (see [Web Application Manifest spec, id member](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#id-member)) with a value of `< our PWA's hostname only >`.

After that, subsequent installs/re-installs now also show the icon normally again on the `chrome://apps` page.

We had no `id` value since inception of our PWA, and according to the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/#id-member), presumably it was correctly defaulting for earlier versions of Chrome.

Now, although the workaround isn't too onerous to talk an end-user through, it is clunky: if/when we figure out how to do this *en masse* via corporate IT tooling and/or Chrome administration, I'll be back.

**UPDATE #1**: Given that the workaround did not involve any changes to our PWA code or manifest (except later to apparently resolve the benign but curious generic placeholder icon that was showing in `chrome://apps`) we do not believe this is related to the underlying web application frameworks or versions. For what it's worth, our PWA is of Angular 1.x vintage.

**UPDATE #2: Forced-Installs Immune?**

Normally, our PWA is self-serve install by end-users but we do have some pre-existing installs on shared/kiosk machines where we had scripted a Registry import to [force-install](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=WebAppInstallForceList) -- so far, even with Chrome 111, **these have yet to exhibit the OP problem.**

Sample Registry `.reg` import file we used:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"WebAppInstallForceList"="[ { \"url\": \"https://our.pwa.host.corp\", \"create_desktop_shortcut\": true, \"default_launch_container\": \"window\" } ]"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"OURAPPNAME"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome_proxy.exe\" --profile-directory=Default --app-id=ourhashedappid"
```

Where `our.pwa.host.corp`, `OURAPPNAME`, and `ourhashedappid` will be unique to your PWA.